# python manage.py migrate [add new model to database]

Tags: python, django

I am doing the tutorial on djangogirls.org website for creating a blog. I am attempting to add a new model to the database and I did the following:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations blog
```

I get list of errors as such:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/marty/swapper/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/marty/swapper/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/marty/swapper/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/marty/swapper/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/marty/swapper/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/marty/swapper/blog/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.util import timezone
ImportError: No module named util
```

I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an import error

```
from django.util import timezone ImportError: No module named util
```

Change to:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

in your blog models and it will be ok

Comment: thank you so much. I am not copy and pasting I am typing to learn and made a stupid error! Thank you so much for your help. Lesson learned...I will check and recheck for typos, thanks Hisgar!